# How do I avoid Race Conditions in UnrealScript?

Tags: udk, unreal

I'm trying to create a pseudo turn based battle system in the Unreal Engine (think Final Fantasy style).

I'm trying to avoid the Enemies and the players attacking while another animation is in progress. I thought the most simple solution is to have a flag somewhere that the player controllers check before starting an animation, and set it to a value before they start, and then reset it when they've finished.

However, I could see this leading to race conditions if two controllers (AI or player) try to access the variable at the same time, then both start their animations.

If I was writing this in Java I'd obviously use synchronized methods, but I haven't come across anything like that in UnrealScript. Is there another way to avoid this? Its probably not the end of the world, as its a pretty unlikely occurance, but I'd like to try and avoid it completely if possible.

Comment: "pseudo turn based?"  It's either turn based or it's not, don't complicate your life =)  Maik Semder left your answer below, and a good one it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> obviously use synchronized methods, but I haven't come across anything
>   like that in UnrealScript

Unreal script is only allowed and runs only in the main-thread, so there is no need to add synchronization objects to Unreal Script. In other words, two lines of script code can never access a variable at the same time from different threads, so no worries about race conditions in Unreal Script :)